# ASP.NET Core exception (the same key has been already added) when running under Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core API project. Previously I was able to successfully run it on Linux(ubuntu):

```
sudo dotnet Project.dll
```

I was also able to run it under Windows

Now something strange has been changed, I guess, and when I run the command:

```
sudo dotnet Project.dll
```

I am getting the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: environment
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Memory.MemoryConfigurationProvider..ctor(MemoryConfigurationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Memory.MemoryConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
```

And then it points to the line

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
```

in my `Program.cs` file, here it is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                    .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

I have already rolled back Startup.cs to the point when it was successfully running but still getting this exception. At the same time I have no problem running this code under Windows. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe it is something in your config file?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dc6fbde39f532bf154ee1eb02d8be08a0a1605e4/src/Config/MemoryConfigurationProvider.cs#L34 Do your json files have the same setting there twice perhaps? _Please update your post to include the contents of both files._

Comment: tbh, it looks like a bug in the MemoryConfigurationProvider class's constructor where it should be adding the key, value pair to the underlying Data dictionary if it doesn't exist, or replacing the value if the key already does exist (to match the behaviour in the underlying abstract ConfigurationProvider class's set method.

Comment: anyway, although it doesn't help your immediate problem, I've submitted a pull request.

Comment: I fixed the issue, the reason was : I used "development" key which is probably using by the system so it was trying to add it twice.